# Автодополнение стандартных функций

Tags: phpstorm

Не подскажите, можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы шторм дополнял функции, например, пишу "for" или "foreach", нажимаю горячую клавишу, и шторм мне выдаёт какой-то шаблон вида

```
for ($i=0; $i<count; $i++) {} 
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {}
```

Нашёл только Ctrl+Shift+Enter, но он не заполняет так.

Может, можно где-то самому прописать такие шаблоны?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно... Настройки скоращений в настройках -> Live Templates. Все настройки hotkey в KeyMap соответственно.

Comment: @noskriptt, точно, это то, что надо. Спасибо.